# UIView border without a black thin line

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to draw a border around an UIView but keep getting a thin black line around the border. 
I'm wondering if it is possible to remove that thin black line from the border...pls see picture.

```
this.rssNumberView = new UIView ();
this.rssNumberView.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
this.rssNumberView.Frame = new RectangleF (66.5f, 0, rssViewHeightAndWidth, rssViewHeightAndWidth);
this.rssNumberView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(35, 44, 119);
this.rssNumberView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
this.rssNumberView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this:

```
this.rssNumberView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
```